# If $\int^1_0 \frac{\sin x}{1+x}dx =I $ then....

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem :

If $\displaystyle \int^1_0 \dfrac{\sin x}{1+x}dx =I $ then $\displaystyle \int^{4\pi}_{4\pi-2} \dfrac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{4\pi +2-x}dx  $ =?

Options are :

(a) $I$ (b) $-I$ (c) $2I$  (d) $-2I$.

Please suggest how to proceed in such problem and how to make to integrals comparable to get the relation between them, will be of great help thanks.

Comment: Try the substitution $u = (4\pi - x)/2$, and remember that $\sin (2\pi - \theta) = - \sin (\theta)$

Comment: @Math-fun Please do not use `\dfrac` and similar constructions in titles.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Many thanks for the comment. I understand then this could make the title "searchable"?!

Comment: @Math-fun There's no difference between \dfrac and \frac from a searchability point of view. But \dfrac uses too much vertical space on the front page.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I see, many thanks. This wold then be a matter of taste, isn't it?

Comment: @Math-fun It's a generally agreed rule. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles/9730#9730

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Great link! Many thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Given $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x }{1+x} = I\;,$$  and  $$\displaystyle \int_{4\pi-2}^{4\pi}\frac{\sin \frac{x}{2}}{4\pi+2-x}dx$$

Now Let $$\displaystyle J = \int_{4\pi-2}^{4\pi}\frac{\sin \frac{x}{2}}{4\pi+2-x}dx$$

Using the formula $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = (b-a)\int_{0}^{1}f\left[(b-a)x+a\right]dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle J = 2\int_{4\pi-2}^{4\pi}\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 x+4\pi-2}{2}\right)}{4\pi+2-\left(2x+4\pi-2\right)}dx = 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin \left(2\pi+x-1\right)}{2(2-x)}dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle J = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin (x-1)}{1+(1-x)}dx = -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin (1-x)}{1+(1-x)}dx$$

Now Put $(1-x) = t$ and $dx = -dt$ and changing limit , we get

$$\displaystyle J = -\times -\int_{1}^{0}\frac{\sin t}{1+t} dt = -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin t}{1+t}dt = -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x}{1+x}dx = -I$$

Above we have used the formulae

$$\displaystyle \bullet\ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = -\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx$$ and $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*
$$
\int_{x} \frac{\sin \frac{x}{2}}{4\pi + 2 -x} = \int_{x = 4\pi - 2u} \frac{-\sin u}{2(1+u)}(-2) = \int_{u}\frac{\sin u}{1+u}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{4\pi-2}^{4\pi}\frac{\sin(x/2)}{4\pi+2-x}dx\underset{y=x-4\pi}{=}\int_{-2}^0\frac{\sin(\frac{y}{2})}{2-y}dy$$

Now, do the substitution $u=-\frac{y}{2}$ to conclude.